# How do I edit my photos like this style? Ambient, cosy etc

Tags: lightroom, photo-editing, ambient-light

I was wondering how you could edit the photo to get it to look like this.

A nice cozy, ambient and soft feeling is quite hard to achieve on lightroom.

Any presets, tips or suggestions are welcome!

[image: Example of photo. Credit: Instagram @kate.simple.life]

Comment: That's shot with a warm light behind the tree against cool daylight from the window. You at least need to show us your start-point & what you have tried so far.

Comment: Re, "how you could edit _the_ photo..." What photo? Do you have an example of a photo that you _wished_ you could make look like the example that you gave? From looking at just the one picture, it's not obvious that the photographer did any "editing" on it at all. Maybe they just photographed a cozy scene with warm, soft lighting. How hard it is to edit a photo to get a desired effect depends a lot on how close the original was to what you intended as the final result.

Comment: "*is quite hard to achieve on lightroom*" You start by trying to achieve it with your camera. Learning all about light and **how to capture it with your camera** is what photography is about. Post processing is a  useful tool but it should not be a crutch, great photos start with the photographers brain and how it uses the camera.

Comment: Disagree with Alaska Man. Getting it right in camera is nice but not always practical - great darkroom and now great post-pro skills can create masterpieces. That being said, your question is "how do I go from A to B" and you've given us a B...but no A. Shooting a similar photo that is 80% of the way there will have a certain sequence of editing steps while shooting something 10% of the way there will require much more work. Both are equally valid questions - but we need to know where to begin to answer this question. Please post a version A so we can edit it to B and show you how to get there

Comment: Hi all, my bad i was just interested in seeing how one could achieve such types of photography. I don't have any photos i wanted to edit in mind, i just wanted to see how people could edit like this. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Perhaps i should have just said what type of lighting and background do i need to capture this ambient lighting. As well as the editing and other post photo stuff.

Comment: See, now that's a completely different question. "Edit like this" doesn't mean much, especially when the original looks to be minimally edited. If you want to re-create an image exactly as is - then ask that question, don't ask how to shoot "like" something - ask how to create something *exactly*. It's a world of difference.

Answer (score 1):

> Perhaps i should have just said what type of lighting and background do i need to capture this ambient lighting. As well as the editing and other post photo stuff. – Joseph

This image is obviously shot with a window in the frame and providing light. Using a sheer white cover over a window is a common method for utilizing window light, which is soft in general and made softer by the sheer covering. It could be a very overcast day or some time of day where the window is getting less light, as it is not very bright. The window light is cool by nature.

The tree and background are lit by warm colored string lights. The light output of the string lights is greater than the light coming in from the window, else it would be overpowered. You get this by shooting a location at the right time of day. Else, you'd have to add more scrim to the window to reduce the light coming in.

You'll get the orange aura/glow naturally from string lights - play around with it.

The editing on this image appears minimal: possibly some curves/levels tweaking, a bit of color balance, and most definitely a vignette. I'm not personally a fan of vignetting images to the point of looking like they were shot through a paper towel roll, but to each their own.

You should practice using just window lighting, and just string lighting, and then combine them. Note specifically the light ratio and how limiting the window light makes the string light aura appear stronger. This is called mixed lighting - or the mixing of artificial and natural lighting. It's most commonly done with flashes/strobes, but can be done with still lights as well. If you want to get more into this, I highly recommend https://strobist.blogspot.com.

Answer (score 0):

I’m not sure about lighting but if I want to achieve a shot like this, I would increase the temperate/warmth and take out as much of the blue’s as possible in the image. I’d maybe even shift the greens to the warmer end of the spectrum too.

Answer (score 0):

That shot looks like no special lighting was used at all.   The warm glow is from the clear incandescent tree lights.  It is shot with a slow shutter speed.  Use a tripod and if you have a subject, don't allow it to move.